# Output text in Browser string by string

Tags: javascript, http

Imagine I have a server script like

```
echo Content-type: text/plane

tail -F /var/log/http/access.log|grep sex
```

Since the browser and web server both buffer output, I will not see results until the transmission ends.

How do I see results, string by string? I can control the server (Perl, PHP) and I can use some pure JS on client. Maybe I should use WebSockets and AJAX somehow?

Comment: try to transmit in chunked transfer encoding mode of http 1.1 (see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for a start). the gist is to add the http header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and to send every chunk of data prefixed with its length in hexadecimal. you should be able to insert the latter by calling sed or awk as the last stage in your pipe. nb: your content-type should be `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

works good enought!
text/plain doesnt work - browsers output only ready content 
but text/html works great!

[root@CENTOS-6 ~]# cat chank-server.sh

```
function log
{
     echo $1 >&2
}


        log 'starting'
sleep 2
        log 'echo headers'
echo HTTP/1.1 200 OK
echo Content-type: text/html
echo Transfer-Encoding: chunked
echo Cache-Control: no-cache
echo
        log 'echo messages'
for i in {1..9}
do
    echo -ne "9\r\n"
    echo -ne "row $i<br>\r\n"
    sleep 2
done
        log 'send last chunk'
echo -ne "0\r\n"
echo -ne "\r\n"

#  | nc -l 9999
```

run as:

[root@CENTOS-6 ~]# while true ; do ./chank-server.sh |  nc -l 9999; done

my browser is a flavour of Chromium, output was:

```
row 1
row 2
row 3
row 4
row 5
row 6
row 7
row 8
row 9
```

And, yes, line by line with 2 sec pause!